# RxSwift breaks Japanese - Romaji input

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, rx-swift, cjk

Add the Japanese - Romaji keyboard to your device.
Settings > Keyboards > Add New Keyboard

When typing on that textfield if you try to type **tada** you won't get the correct input **ただ** but **たdあ**.

Any ideas on how to tackle this?

```swift
let value: BehaviorRelay<String> = .init(value: "")

self.textField.textField?.rx.text.orEmpty
            .bind(to: self.value)
            .disposed(by: self.disposeBag)

//same for this
self.textField.textField?.rx.text.orEmpty.asDriver()
    .drive(onNext: { (value) in
                self.value.accept(value)
     })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem as you.
I recommend to use two-way binding directly.
https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxBinding

```
viewModel.text <~> textFeild.rx.text ~ disposeBag
```

If you do not want to use this way, you should not update the text of textFiled if the value is same as the old value.